# Push to an array at a specific path of a useReducer's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a (functional) component named `Form`, in which I used `useReducer()` hook to set up a state that looks like this:

```
{
  content: {
    profile: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe'
    },
    experiences: [
      {
        employer: 'CompanyX',
        position: 'CEO'
      },
      {
        employer: 'CompanyY',
        position: 'Intern'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I want to push a new experience to the experiences array and I'm looking for the best way to write my reducer's case. Here's the solution I came up with:

```
// reducer.js

case 'ADD_EXPERIENCE': { 
  newState = _.clone(state);
  newState.content.experiences = _.concat(state.content.experiences, action.newExperience);
  return newState;
}
```

However, this doesn't look elegant to me. I was wondering if you guys have any better solution. E.g., is lodash's `setWith()` method appropriate?

```
// reducer.js

case 'ADD_EXPERIENCE': { 
  return _.setWith(
    _.clone(state),
    'content.experiences',
    action.newExperience,
    () => ???
  )
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally:

```
case 'ADD_EXPERIENCE':
  return _.updateWith(
    _.clone(state),
    'content.experiences',
    (value) => [...value, action.newExperience],
    _.clone
  );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ES6 spread operator `...` to destructure the state and the new experiences array and return the new state, like this:

```
case 'ADD_EXPERIENCE': { 
    return {
        ...state,
        content: {
            ...state.content,
            experiences: [...state.content.experiences, action.newExperience]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about this. However, if the state object gets deeper, I mean if it has more nesting, this solution can become tedious. Furthermore, it will force all the components to rerender, even if the value they're listening to hasn't changed (e.g. content.profile)

Comment: That depends, you shouldn't compare objects to objects and arrays to arrays, because such comparison compares pointers and not values, and are rarely the same between two consecutive renders. I agree regarding the nested objects part, in this case your first solution is elegant enough and you can use the spread operator or ES6's concat method instead of lodash

Comment: @TheoAvoyne this solution preserves the identity of `state.content.profiles` object and won't re-render any memoized components that depend (only) on it, same as shallow `_.clone`